# Finding subsequence using bit manipulation programming questions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

How to approach for finding solution to subsequence and subsets problems like finding the subsequence or subsets of an array which satisfy particular condition and  should be solved using bits manipulation and what is the best time complexity to which it can be reduced to.
I have started practicing a lot of coding questions these days.

Need little help.
I expect some proper approach which should be followed to solve that's kind of problems.

Comment: What are subsquence and subset problems? Do you have an example? How did you try to solve it?

Comment: Not all problems lend themselves to solutions that involve bit twiddling tricks. It sounds like you have some vague solution ("I want to twiddle some bits") that's looking for a problem. That's not the kind of question that Stackoverflow is meant for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count from 0 to (2<sup>`set.size()`</sup> - 1) (inclusive). Retrieve the elements corresponding to 1 bits in the current count. The set will have to be ordered to retrieve elements by index, of course.

The only tricky part is pulling out the elements corresponding to the 1 bits in the current count. Here's pseudocode for one way to do that:

```
for (int pos = 0, mask = 1; mask <= currentCount; mask <<= 1; ++pos) {
    if ((currentCount & mask) != 0) {
        include element at pos in the current subset
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that the original set size is no more than the number of bits available for whatever integer type you are using for the count and mask.

Implementation in Java will look like this:

```
private static void findSubsets(int array[]) {
    int numOfSubsets = 1 << array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSubsets; i++) {
        int pos = array.length - 1;
        int bitmask = i;

        System.out.print("{");
        while (bitmask > 0) {
            if ((bitmask & 1) == 1)
                System.out.print(array[pos] + ",");
            bitmask >>= 1;
            pos--;
        }
        System.out.print("}");
    }
}
```